# How to make a graduate sum of row by pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

My goal is to sum rows step by step and simultaneously record the value on the new column.

Words may not be clear, for example:

[image]

And I want to make a graduate sum of money and make a new column:

[image]

How could I make it? I have pondering for a while...hope someone could help me!

Comment: `df['money'].cumsum()`.